# How to Parse this JSON with LibGDX

Tags: json, libgdx

```
 "components":[  
        {  
           "class":"AssetReference",
           "asset":{  
              "class":"TextureRegionAsset",
              "relativePath":"gfx/opengraph.png"
           }
        },
        {  
           "class":"Layer"
        },
        {  
           "class":"ProtoVisSprite",
           "width":5,
           "height":5
        },
        {  
           "class":"Transform",
           "x":0.13817275,
           "y":2.8430145,
           "scaleX":0.2,
           "scaleY":0.2
        },
        {  
           "class":"Origin"
        },
        {  
           "class":"Tint"
        },
        {  
           "class":"Renderable",
           "zIndex":2
        },
        {  
           "class":"VisID",
           "id":"scratch"
        }
     ]
```

Im having some issues in parsing the nested asset with LibGDX. Does anyone know how to assign asset to AssetReference with the relativePath from TextureRegionAsset?

I know I could strip out the "class" handling and simple parse the JSON but I need to be able to handle this with LibGDX.

Ideally Im looking to parse the data and create a sprite from the JSON.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `JsonReader` and get `JsonValue` for that.

```
JsonReader json = new JsonReader();
JsonValue base = json.parse(Gdx.files.internal("file.json"));

//print json to console
System.out.println(base);

//get the component values
JsonValue component = base.get("components");

//print class value to console
System.out.println(component.getString("class"));

//array objects in json if you would have more components
for (JsonValue component : base.get("components"))
{
    System.out.println(component.getString("class"));
    System.out.println(component.get("asset").getString("class");
    System.out.println(component.get("asset").getString("relativePath");
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Funnily enough it solves a few other issues I was having. Curiosity still drives me to find a  100% LibGDX solution, but that is me just being subborn :)

Comment: My mistake, I just noticed that JsonReader and JsonValue are both part of LibGDX. So thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a useful libgdx wiki page for this:

https://libgdx.com/wiki/utils/reading-and-writing-json

Apparently it seems to work fine with nested classes on its own already.
The wiki page has this example:

```
Json json = new Json();
Person person = json.fromJson(Person.class, text);
```

Using the following as *text*:

```
{
    class: com.example.Person,
    numbers: [
        {
            class: com.example.PhoneNumber,
            number: "206-555-1234",
            name: Home
        },
        {
            class: com.example.PhoneNumber,
            number: "425-555-4321",
            name: Work
        }
    ],
    name: Nate,
    age: 31
}
```

This is using an example class "Person" with the following properties:

- ArrayList numbers
- String name
- int age

The String **text** is the result of `json.toJson(person)`. Your resulting serialized string seems the same format, which makes me assume you're already using the Json serializer, but not the unserializer.

Comment: SE aims to have maintainable answers so by just posting a link you are not following this principle since that link could die. You can use links to strengthen your answer but the answer should stand on it's own. You can also quote the link and give credit to the author, but simply copy pasting is discouraged as well.

Comment: Sigh. Since it's the official wiki, I assume it'll never go down. Quoting the page is a big pain, but I'll edit my answer a bit.

Comment: Yet the previous google where migrated too. You don't have to quote, you can write it yourself too ;)